# Excel Sort based on first column

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Just a quick question. Say I have four columns of data A, B, C and D.

`A   B   C   D
10  1   10  8
40  2   30  9
30  3   60  12
60  4   50  11
50  5   40  13
20  6   20  15`

How would I sort columns C and D based on the order of A? i.e I would want the following result;

`A   B   C   D
10  1   10  8
40  2   40  13
30  3   30  9
60  4   60  12
50  5   50  11
20  6   20  15`

See how Column C has arranged to be the same as A and The values in D corresponding to their neighboring cell in C has moved with them. I tried highlighting all the columns and sorting the data based on column A but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Regards,
Jer

Comment: So you are looking to change your data? Once you do this Excel will not be able to get the data back to the original state.

Comment: Will column A and C have same value but in different order?

Answer (score 0):

In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references. Select "Microstoft ActiveX data objects 2.8 Library.

```
Private Sub CommandButton26_Click()

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "ColumnC", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "ColumnD", adInteger
        .Open
    End With

    lrow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in Columns C and D
    Do While lrow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("Row").Value = lrow
        rs.Fields("ColumnC").Value = ws.Range("C" & lrow).Value
        rs.Fields("ColumnD").Value = ws.Range("D" & lrow).Value
        rs.Update

        lrow = lrow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lrow).Activate
    Loop

    'Now go through and rewrite columns C and D based on what is in A
    lrow = 1
    Do While lrow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.Filter = "ColumnC='" & ws.Range("A" & lrow).Value & "'"
        'If we have a match, write C and D
        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & lrow).Value = rs.Fields("ColumnC").Value
            ws.Range("D" & lrow).Value = rs.Fields("ColumnD").Value
        End If

        lrow = lrow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that was a poor example I gave. Imagine if column A was in the order ``10
40
30
60
50
20`` Then column C could not be sorted using the sort function as A is neither in ascending or descending order. Sorry for my earlier mistake.

Comment: I have changed my answer based on your new data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small macro that you use which will sort your columns C based on column A and column D will be automatically sorted.
It's uses **`'MATCH'`** function. I've placed the comments for your understanding.
Assuming your data is in column A:D and having header.

```
Sub test1()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long

    'SELECTING THE SHEET (CHANGE ME)
    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'SETTING # OF ROWS
    rw = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'LOOPING AND PLACING FORMULA IN TEMPORARY COLUMN E
    For i = 2 To rw
        sht.Cells(i, 5).Value = "=MATCH(C" & i & ",$A$2:$A$" & rw & ",0)"
    Next

    'SORTING COLUMNS C,D AND E IN ASCENDING ORDER (WHICH WILL BE EXACTLY LIKE COLUMN A)
    Range("C2:E" & rw).Sort Key1:=Range("E2:E" & rw), Order1:=xlAscending

    'CLEARING THE TEMPORARY COLUMN E
    Range("E2:E" & rw).Clear

    'RELEASING THE OBJECT
    Set sht = Nothing
End Sub
```